# Conditional in Angular 2 Component Selector

Tags: angular

With native HTML `input` tags, I can do bindings on the type attribute like,

```
<input [type]="_field.type">
```

The input element would dynamically change according to the value of `_field.type`

However, if I have multiple components like this,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field-option[type=options]',
  templateUrl: ''
})
```

And use it like,

```
<field-option [type]="_field.type">
```

It does not work, it does not bind.

I can however, get it to work with static value,

```
<field-option [type]="options">
```

I would like to know how to get this to work?

Comment: Did you try attribute binding? `<field-option [attr.type]="_field.type">`

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6970#issuecomment-182025921

Comment: Ah, guess it's a bug ;(

Comment: @Sasxa `[type]="_field.type"` this doesn't do anything to DOM (no `type` attribute at all), `[attr.type]="_field.type"` does adds `type` attributes, but doesn't renders the right component. Confusing.

Comment: Does your `<field-option>` component have `@Input() type`? Maybe you could just use selector `'field-option'` and use type as property...

Comment: @Sasxa ya, had to fall back to that for now. hopefully they'll support `selector: 'field-option[type=options]'` syntax eventually. much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input [type]="_field.type">
```

works because it's handled by the browser.

```
<field-option [type]="_field.type">
```

would need Angular support but that's not (yet?) implemented.

As a workaround you could do something like

```
<field-option *ngIf="_field.type='type1'" [type]="type1">
<field-option *ngIf="_field.type='type2'" [type]="type2">
```

I know, cumbersome :-/

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6970